# generating executable file from .ll files

Tags: llvm

I'm writing a front-end for `LLVM` with java. My front-end produces `.ll` files. Then I use the following commands to convert these files to an executable file:

```
1. for each .ll file I use `'llvm-as file.ll'` to create  a bitcode file
2. use `'llvm-ld -o executable my-bitcode-files -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lstdc++'` to
```

generate  an executable file.

Then when I run the executable file, I get the following error:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '_Znwm' which could not be resolved!
```

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate native executable, not the IR + wrapper. Try to add -native to llvm-ld cmdline.

Comment: Please give detailed output. For example give the complete command.